# If a shipboard antenna isn't "grounded" to the water on a fiberglass-hulled boat, would using the radio (TX or RX) attract more lightning?

Tags: antenna, water, lightning, static

Because of my poor understanding of the interaction between static and flowing electrical charge, I don't trust my intuition about the answer to this question.

Essentially I'm asking if there could be a potential increase of a static charge imbalance on the antenna's surface due to current running to/through it, one that would significantly increase the potential difference between it and the thundercloud(s).

I don't recall ever getting "zapped" when I touched a ham radio antenna while it was in use, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything.

Comment: A *static electric field* (perhaps 100V/m) exists above earth, regardless of the weather. If you raise an ungrounded antenna wire into the air, it can become charged to a substantial voltage, even on a clear day. Rain, sleet, falling snow can also transfer charge to an antenna. Perhaps a feeble zap compared to a lightning strike. A large antenna and/or a long transmission line might produce a dangerous zap.

Comment: @glen_geek 100V/m? that's huge. Never heard this. Could you elaborate on this or point me to some refs?

Comment: You can try: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electricity. Charge density in this field is very low - it is easily distorted simply by standing upright and it is not easy to measure. But it can be dangerous when a conductor is raised that collects charge into one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The voltages generated by RF transmission are not significant when compared to the 10-100 million volts of a lightning strike so the use of the radio will not be an increased risk. Using the radio in a thunderstorm however is unwise due to the risk of personal injury and equipment damage if you do get a strike.

By far the biggest risk is the presence of the antenna particularly if it is a vertical whip. Raising a vertical conductor over a flat surface is asking for a strike.

To mitigate equipment and structure damage it is common practice to provide an antenna switch which connects the antenna to the sea through a low impedance path and can be used when the radio is not in use or if lightning is likely.

Answer (score 4):

> *If a shipboard antenna isn't "grounded" to the water on a
> fiberglass-hulled boat, would using the radio (tx or rx) attract more
> lightning?*

Lightning almost effortlessly manages to transition the several km gap between cloud and earth so, the thickness of a ship's hull is barely relevant.

Comment: Furthermore, if there is a nice Marconian whip antenna, pointed towards the sky, it becomes a nice lightning rod...